# Can't use new Angular Fire 2 update with angular seed

Tags: angular, firebase, systemjs, angularfire2, angular-seed

I am try to download `AngularFir2 v4.0.0-rc.2` to angular-seed repo https://github.com/mgechev/angular-seed/

but I got this error while running `npm run start-deving` [image: error]

The following lines is extended from the files I believe the error is related to:

**karma.conf.js**

```
{ pattern: 'node_modules/firebase/**/*.js', included: false, watched: false },
{ pattern: 'node_modules/angularfire2/bundles/*.umd.js', included: false, watched: false },
```

**project.config.ts**

```
let additionalPackages: ExtendPackages[] = [
  { name: 'firebase', path: 'node_modules/firebase'},
  { name: 'angularfire2', path : 'node_modules/angularfire2/bundles'}
];    
this.addPackagesBundles(additionalPackages);
```

**test-config.js**

```
System.config({
  baseURL: '/base/',
  paths: {
    angular2: 'node_modules/angular2',
    angularfire2 : 'node_modules/angularfire2',
    rxjs: 'node_modules/rxjs',
  },
  packages: {
    '': {
      defaultExtension: 'js'
    },
    rxjs: {
      defaultExtension: 'js'
    }
  }
});
```

**package.json**

```
"angularfire2": "^4.0.0-rc.2",
"firebase": "^4.3.0",
```

It maybe SystemJS is not not reading any thing from Angular Fire, because I got no error in vscode when importing `{ AngularFireDatabase, FirebaseListObservable } from 'angularfire2/database'`

Comment: Probably this is because angularfire2 deploy not transpiled sources? Some time ago I got similar problem. I had to manually transpile angulafire2 sources via babel.

Comment: There's folder called `es2015` inside ./node_modules/AngularFire2/. It contains 8 files. Is this what I need to import ?

Comment: You can try. I end up with enabling transpile on it.